# Why is Apple Silicon Share Disk so slow?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt, mac-mini, target-disk-mode, share-disk

I've been copying files from an M1 Mac mini and a 2018 15" MacBook Pro to a 2023 16" MacBook Pro.

With the 2018, I can use [Target Disk Mode](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-mac-computers-target-disk-mode-mchlp1443/mac). I didn't time it, but it went so fast as to not bear notice.

With the mini, I have to use [Share Disk](https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/transfer-files-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchlb37e8ca7/14.0/mac/14.0). It seemed very slow, so I benchmarked it—it was going at about 27 MB/s.

I rebooted the mini and instead used a direct Ethernet connection (CalDigit TS3 Plus Ethernet to Mac mini built-in Ethernet). That is benchmarking at 104 MB/s.

I'm curious what's making Share Disk so slow, or if that's just intrinsic to the technology—or if, in fact, my experience is very unique. I used the same Thunderbolt 3 cable in both cases, plugged into the same port on the 2023.

Comment: Can you please add guidance/details to the `share-disk` tag you just created?

Comment: @nohillside Proposed. Thanks for the reminder.